# Python: how to print without white spaces?

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print 'Answer',i,':'
```

Output is:

```
Answer 1 :
Answer 2 :
Answer 3 :
Answer 4 :
```

I want it to be like this:

```
Answer 1:
Answer 2:
Answer 3:
Answer 4:
```

i.e. without spaces in between integer and ':'
How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print 'Answer {0}:'.format(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print "Answer %d:" % i
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print 'Answer '+str(i)+':'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print "Answer", str(i)+':'
```

When you are printing with `','`, the space is added automatically, you can concatenate output by either using `+` or positioning strings next to each other (in Python 2.x), like so:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print 'Answer'+str(i), ':'
    print 'Answer%d'':'%i
```

Check the difference!